# How to use a variable from a Makefile in #ifdef in C++ file

Tags: c++, makefile, compiler-flags

> Makefile

```
ifeq ($(wifiSim),1)
WIFISIM :=1
endif

all: test.cpp

test.cpp : test.o
        ./a.out

test.o :
        c++ test.cpp
```

> test.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{    
        #ifdef WIFISIM
                cout << "Inside wifisim = 1" << endl;
        #else
              cout << "Outside wifisim = 1" << endl;
        #endif

        return 0;
}
```

I want to use the `WIFISIM` in the `test.cpp`.
I am running `make wifiSim=1 all`
But the else is being executed in `test.cpp`

Is there any way I can do it without doing any changes in the way the compilation for `test.cpp` is done, because I need to use this flag WIFISIM in many files and I do not want to change the way compilation for them is being done.

Comment: Where should the compilation get the value of `WIFISIM` from? Where are you telling `c++` about it?

Comment: You can create a conditional variable that expands to `-DWIFISIM` and add it to the compiler flags.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may do something like this

```
ifeq ($(wifiSim),1)
    WIFISIM := -DWIFISIM
endif

all: test.cpp

test.cpp : test.o
        ./a.out

test.o :
        c++ $(WIFISIM) test.cpp
```

> *"Is there any way I can do it without doing any changes in the way the compilation for "test.cpp" is done, because I need to use this flag WIFISIM in many files and I do not want to change the way compilation for them is being done."*

No, there's no way without changing the compiler call action in the rule.

You should change your strategy writing the makefile. `make` actually supports [implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules) how to create a `.o` file from a `.cpp` and uses an action that looks like

```
$(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c
```

Thus you could add the `-DWIFISIM` conditionally to the `$(CPPFLAGS)` or  `$(CXXFLAGS)` variables, and it will be applied for all `.cpp` files compiled.

Sample using implicit rules:

```
ifeq ($(wifiSim),1)
    CXXFLAGS += -DWIFISIM
endif

SRC_FILES := test.cpp abc.cpp yxz.cpp
OBJ_FILES := $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(SRC_FILES))

all: test

test: $(OBJ_FILES)
```

Comment: Is there any way I can do it without doing any changes in the way the compilation for "test.cpp" is done, because I need to use this flag WIFISIM in many files and I do not want to change the way compilation for them is being done.

Comment: @a2n3k7it You should use the implicit compilation rules (`.o : .cpp`) then and add that to the `$(CXXFLAGS)` variable.

Comment: @a2n3k7it: No; not if your makefiles are written as shown.  If you used macros everywhere, and/or the built-in C++ compilation rules, you might be in with a fighting chance, but not with the compilation lines written verbatim as shown in the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you use GCC, you may use option `-DWIFISIM` as options passed to GCC/G++. Other compilers have similiar options, such as `/D` in Microsoft Visual Studio:

```
CXXFLAGS = 

ifeq ($(wifiSim),1)
CXXFLAGS += -DWIFISIM
endif

all: test.cpp

test.cpp : test.o
    ./a.out

test.o :
    c++ $(CXXFLAGS) test.cpp
```

Result:

```
$ make -n wifiSim=1
c++  -DWIFISIM test.cpp
./a.out
$ make -n
c++  test.cpp
./a.out
```

Comment: Note that VC++ actually accepts either `/` or `-` to signal a flag.

Comment: Looks like the OP uses clang. But anyway the `-D` option is available in that for for almost all preprocessors I've ever met.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Isn't `clang` C++ compiler is called `clang++`? On my machine `c++` is symlink to `g++-4.8`